# How to run all tests with minitest?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I downloaded source code for a project, found a bug, and fixed it.

Now I want to run tests to find out if I have broken anything.

The Tests are in minitest DSL.

How do I run them all at once?

I searched for applicable rake tasks etc, but I  didn't find any.

Comment: Did you run any individual tests? If so, how?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Here's a link to [Rake::TestTask](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/TestTask.html).

There is an example in the page to get you started.
I'll post another one that I'm using right now for a gem:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.pattern = "spec/*_spec.rb"
end
```

As you can see, I assume that my files are all in `/lib` and that my specs are in `/spec` and are named `whatever_spec.rb`

Comment: Putting what you @locks mentions in a Rakefile will allow you to just run `rake test`

Comment: Is it possible to run all tests distributed in different directories using with minitest-metadata tags?

Answer (score 30):

locks' answer is better, but I also wanted to point out that you can also run minitest directly from the command like with the ruby command.  To run the tests in the spec/calculator_spec.rb file run:

```
$ ruby spec/calculator_spec.rb
```

Remember to include the following code in the calculator_spec.rb file:

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
```

To run all tests in the spec/ directory, use the following command (see this post for more details [Globbing doesn't work with Minitest - Only one file is run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048579/globbing-doesnt-work-with-minitest-only-one-file-is-run?lq=1))

```
$ for file in spec/*.rb; do ruby $file; done
```

Answer (score 20):

This is what [`Rake::TestTask`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/TestTask.html) does under the hood, more or less:

```
ruby -Ilib -e 'ARGV.each { |f| require f }' ./test/test*.rb
```

Note: `lib` & `test/test*.rb` (above) are the defaults but `test` & `test/*_test.rb`, respectively, are more typical.

Source: [rake/testtask.rb at c34d9e0 line 169](https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/c34d9e0afbaee050a4202d045a42efb8aae65117/lib/rake/testtask.rb#L169)

If you're using JRuby and want to avoid paying the startup cost twice (once for Rake and then once for the subprocess that Rake starts), just use that command.

Comment: Documentation link is broken here.

Comment: So weird how `./test/*_test.rb` works but not `test/*_test.rb`. You can also use `ruby -I lib -e 'ARGV.each { |f| load f }' test/*_test.rb` which seems to work with both `./test/*_test.rb` and  `test/*_test.rb`

Answer (score 16):

Here is my entire `rakefile`, which I put in my top directory:

```
task :default => :test
task :test do
  Dir.glob('./test/*_test.rb').each { |file| require file}
end
```

To run all my test files at once, I just type `rake`. That's it!

Make sure to have `require 'minitest/autorun'` at the top of each of your Minitest files. Dir.glob definitely DOES work with Minitest.

To get pretty, colored Minitest output, with names of all my test methods, I have the file `minitest_helper.rb` in my /test directory. (Had to install the gem minitest-reporters):

```
require 'minitest/reporters'
Minitest::Reporters.use!(Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new)
require 'minitest/autorun'
```

I just had to `require_relative './minitest_helper'` at the top of each of my test files.

Comment: This is nice, except for the fact if you use bundler... in that case, every require statement will fill because the gems wouldn't be on the `$LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: I get no output at all when I run `rake`. I didn't use reporters, do I need to?

Answer (score 7):

This can also be done via a Makefile.

```
default:
  echo "Dir.glob('./test/*_test.rb').each { |file| require file}" | ruby
```

running `make` will run all your tests.

Answer (score 4):

`$ rake test` ran out of the rails 5.0 box.

Comment: This does not run my system tests, just the component tests.

Comment: Keep in mind that `rails test` is not the same as `rake test` https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27088#issuecomment-261385679. You need to use `bin/rails test` instead to be on the safe side. btw, the author didn't mention he uses Rails, so not sure how relevant it is.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this using only Ruby's standard library is with [`Dir.glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob). From within a ruby file, this would look like this:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

Dir.glob("**/*Test.rb") { |f| require_relative(f) }
```

Or from the commandline, you can use this command:

```
ruby -I . -e "require 'minitest/autorun'; Dir.glob('**/*Test.rb') { |f| require(f) }"
```

`Dir.glob('**/*Test.rb')` recursively searches the current directory for any file which matches `*Test.rb`, so we simply take all those files and `require` or `require_relative` them. From the commandline, `require_relative` fails, so we use `require` but first add the current directory to the `$LOAD_PATH` through `-I .`

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a very old question, but `rake test` works for me in Rails 4.2, including files under test/ as well as test/integration/, test/unit/, etc.

Answer (score 0):

On rails7 you have the following tasks:

```bash
rake test
rake test:all
```

First one skips system tests, second one does them all

Answer (score 0):

## March 2024 update:

`minitest` gem has a built-in task for that. Add the following code to your `Rakefile.rb` file

```
require 'minitest/test_task'

Minitest::TestTask.create do |t|
  t.framework = %(require "test/test_helper.rb")
  t.libs = %w[test .]
  t.test_globs = ['test/**/*_test.rb']
end
```

and run `rake test`. Tune [`.create` defaults](https://github.com/minitest/minitest/blob/v5.22.2/lib/minitest/test_task.rb#L109) when needed.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have rake, try this:

http://blog.gingergriffis.com/post/85871430778/ruby-how-to-run-all-tests-in-a-directory

```
# run_all_tests.rb

require 'find'
require 'optparse'

options = {
  :exclude => [],
}

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('--exclude Comma Separated String',
          'Test scripts to exclude') do |css|
    options[:exclude] = css.split(',')
  end
end.parse!

commands = []

Find.find(File.dirname(__FILE__)) do |path|
  Find.prune if path =~ /#{__FILE__}$/
    if !File.directory?(path) && (path =~ /(.*)\.rb$/)
      if options[:exclude].none? {|e| path.include?(e)}
        commands << "ruby #{path}"
      end
    end
end
command_string = commands.join(" && ")
exec(command_string)
```

Comment: That is very costly since it requires a ruby interpreter for each test you want to be running. Also it is a lot of code for doing a very simple thing. Have a look at Theo's solution. It does the very same thing, more efficient, and you also don't need `rake`.