# How to use Ruby MiniTest::Spec with Rails for API integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, specifications, minitest

I'm building an app including a Rails API and want to use Ruby MiniTest::Spec to test.

What's a good way to set it up?

For example, good directory organization, good way to include files, etc.?

I'm using the guidelines in the book Rails 3 In Action which uses RSpec and has a great chapter on APIs. The big change is preferring MiniTest::Spec.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Answering with what I've found so far in case it's helpful to other developers....

#### spec/api/items_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

class ItemsSpec < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  before do
    @item = Factory.create(:item)
  end

  describe "items that are viewable by this user" do
    it "responds with good json" do
      get "/api/items.json"
      response.success?.must_equal true
      body.must_equal Item.all.to_json
      items = JSON.parse(response.body)
      items.any?{|x| x["name"] == @item.name}.must_equal true
    end
  end

end
```

#### spec/spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'action_controller/test_case'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'miniskirt'
require 'factories'
require 'mocha'

# Support files                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Dir["#{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}/support/*.rb"].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

#### spec/factories/item.rb

```
Factory.define :item do |x|
  x.name { "Foo" }
end
```

#### app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb

```
class Api::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json
end
```

#### app/controllers/api/items_controller.rb

```
class Api::ItemsController < Api::BaseController
  def index
    respond_with(Item.all)
  end
end
```

#### config/routes.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :items
  end
end
```

#### Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'capybara'  # Integration test tool to simulate a user on a website.
  gem 'capybara_minitest_spec'  # MiniTest::Spec expectations for Capybara node matchers.
  gem 'mocha'  # Mocking and stubbing library for test doubles for Ruby.
  gem 'minitest', '>= 3'  # Ruby's core TDD, BDD, mocking, and benchmarking.
  gem 'minitest-capybara'  #  Add Capybara driver switching parameters to minitest/spec.
  gem 'minitest-matchers'  # RSpec/Shoulda-style matchers for minitest.
  gem 'minitest-metadata'  # Annotate tests with metadata key-value pairs.
  gem 'minitest-spec-rails'  # Drop in MiniTest::Spec support for Rails 3.
  gem 'miniskirt'  # Factory creators to go with minitest.
  gem 'ruby-prof'  # Fast code profiler for Ruby with native C code.
end
```