# Globbing doesn't work with Minitest - Only one file is run

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

I have placed all my specs in `specs/*.rb`.

However, when I run Minitest with `ruby spec/**/*_spec.rb`, only one file is run.

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not minitest specific, but Ruby. You are effectively running a ruby program which knows nothing about the program being run.

Ruby does not support running multiple files at once afaik, so if you want to get a similar result you could try something like:

```
for file in spec/**/*_spec.rb; do ruby $file; done
```

**UPDATE**: for what you want you should probably create a Rake task as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788288/how-to-run-all-the-tests-with-minitest)

Comment: Thanks Oscar. I checked that link out. The reason I wanted to run directly is because running a `rake test` seems super slow compared to say, your suggestion above. I tried to place it in `lib/tasks/minitest.rake` and running `rake test`, and it took ages. Any thoughts on that.

Comment: It dependes on what you're loading on your Rake task. Rake by itself is fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [testrbl](https://github.com/grosser/testrbl) third party gem to run multiple Minitest files on the command line. You could also use the `mtest` bin from [maxitest](https://github.com/grosser/maxitest) extensions.

Using a `for` loop in bash will incur overhead of loading your application/library for every test you pass it. If you have just ten tests, and you're testing a Rails app that takes 5 seconds to boot, that's over a minute of totally unnecessary load time.