# Makefile for Ruby tests

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, makefile, rake

I know about [Rake::TestTask](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/TestTask.html).

But, how would I write a Makefile to achive similar functionality?

I want to be able to run all my Ruby tests by running:

```
make test
```

It'd also be nice to have a way to run one test file, e.g.:

```
TEST=just_one_file.rb make test
```

I use MiniTest.

I want this because I like Make, and I want to start using it more.

I figured seeing this example would help me.

I also don't understand what rake test does under the scenes, so seeing the Makefile might help me understand how tests run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Directory Structure

```
├── Makefile
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── views
├── test
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── test_helper.rb
```

#### Makefile

```
TEST := test/**/*_test.rb

.PHONY : test

test :
    ruby -Itest -e 'ARGV.each { |f| require "./#{f}" }' $(TEST)
```

See [how to run all the tests with minitest?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677149/242933)

#### Test Commands

```
make test # runs all tests
make test TEST=test/controllers/* # runs all tests in test/controllers
make test TEST='test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb test/controllers/groups_controller_test.rb' # runs some tests
make test TEST=test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb # runs a single test
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just run `MiniTest` [from command line](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#running-your-tests):

This is how you run 1 file:

```
$ ruby -Ilib:test test/minitest/test_minitest_unit.rb
```

To run everything, you need to collect all files by some pattern (`Rake::TestTask` by default uses `test/test*.rb`) and then supply it to above command as arguments, something like this

```
$ find test -name 'test*.rb' | xargs ruby -Ilib:test
```