# ruby - how to use tags within examples for minitest

Tags: ruby, testing, tags, minitest

I have

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/tags'
require 'rspec/expectations'

describe "One happy and one sad test", :happy do
  include RSpec::Matchers

  it "it is true" do
    expect(true).to be true
  end 
  it "it is false" do
    expect(false).to be true
  end 
end
```

and the `describe` tag works but I can't add a tag to the `it`, as in

```
it "it is true", :happy do
  expect(true).to be true
end
```

without getting:

$ ruby test_example.rb

```
...1: from test_example.rb:9:in `block in <main>'

.../minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest/spec.rb:212:in `it':
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1) (ArgumentError)
```

I have the minitest-tags gem in my Gem file and have bundled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [minitest-tags](https://github.com/wenbo/minitest-tags) gem does not accept tags as additional arguments, instead they are given in the title text:

```
it "does stuff(some,tags)"
```

If however you want more `describe`-like tags, then I think you want to use [minispec-metadata](https://github.com/ordinaryzelig/minispec-metadata) instead:

```
it "does stuff", :some, :tags
```

Then you can run selected tests using the `--tag` option:

```
$ ruby test_example.rb --tag some --tag tags
```

Note that the *minitest-tags* gem is quite outdated, and it will conflict with *minispec-metadata* if both are installed at the same time! I recommend uninstalling *minitest-tags*, and going with *minispec-metadata* instead.

**Note from OP** - So I ended up having:

```
require 'minitest/spec'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minispec-metadata'
require 'rspec/expectations'

describe "One happy and one sad test" do
  include RSpec::Matchers

  it "is is true", :happy do
    expect(true).to be true
  end 
  it "it is false", :sad do
    expect(true).to be true
  end 
end
```

Comment: Yes worked.  I did have to remove the top level describe tag for correct functionality though

Comment: it seemed to over-ride somehow so run happy actually ran both until i removed it from the describe

Comment: Ok I see now. Right. Good point. I think you cannot have the same named tag on both `describe` and `it`.

Comment: @Casper thanks for the answer. It works great but what if we want to execute the whole test directory using with tag? I have spec directory and 3 sub directories in it. When I run "ruby spec/**/*.rb -t authorization",  just the first file in the directory starts to execution.

Comment: @buurkeey Yeah that won't work because the `ruby` executable does not allow multiple scripts on the command line. This is a Ruby issue, not a test issue. You can look for an answer in the link below, which should give you some ideas what to try. If those do not help, then you can think about creating a new SO question for your specific issue. But first look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788288/how-to-run-all-tests-with-minitest

Comment: Thank you @Casper. I tried it using with minispec-metadata and rakefile. ' rake test TESTOPTS="--tag=authorization" ' command executed all test which tagged with "authorization" under the spec directory as I expected.