# Pure Ruby app - how to run all tests at once

Tags: ruby, minitest

I've got pure Ruby App for which I wrote few minitests. For example below test works well:

```
require 'pry'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'active_support'
require_relative '../../../../src/parsers/incoming_events/continue_quiz'

module Parsers
  module IncomingEvents
    class ContinueQuizTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
      test 'parse JSON to Lexis Nexis format' do
        assert_equal expected_hash, service.call
      end

      private

      def service
        @service ||= ::Parsers::IncomingEvents::ContinueQuiz.new(event: event)
      end

      def event
        File.read('test/fixtures/files/continue_event.json')
      end

      def expected_hash
        JSON.parse(File.read('test/fixtures/files/incoming_events/continue_expected_result.json'))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To run this thing I need to write this command in the console `ruby test/src/parsers/responses/continue_quiz_test.rb` which is a little annoying because I have 10 of these tests. Is it possible to run all the tests at once from the "test" folder?

I was hoping for the `ruby test test/` command but my guess is that this is some kind of Rails magic command.

Comment: Does `ruby test/*` not work to run all files in your `test` directory? (You have to specify files for ruby to run, not a directory.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788288/how-to-run-all-tests-with-minitest

Comment: You said it's a pure Ruby app, but you mentioned Rails in your question. Is it a Rails application? Also, from your test, it seems to be a Rails application. In this case, `rake test` or `rails test` should work.

Comment: @Sidney No, it's a pure Ruby app why do you think it's also Rails?

Comment: @JohnP After running `ruby test/*` I'm getting this error: `ruby: Is a directory -- test/fixtures (LoadError)`

Comment: OK, so perhaps you need to use `ruby test/*.rb` or to rename your files so you have a common part (e.g. they're all `test_foo_bar.rb`, so you can use `ruby test/test_*`). You should just need to pass the files (and nothing but the files) to your `ruby` command.

Comment: Ok, but what if I have one test inside `test/src/parsers/responses/continue_quiz_test.rb` and another in `test/src/services/requests_test.rb` ? BTW I've got two tests inside `test/src/parsers/responses/` but only one test was fired after the command `ruby test/src/parsers/**/*.rb`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run all tests with minitest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788288/how-to-run-all-tests-with-minitest)